# Shell Script how to pass an argument with spaces inside a variable

Tags: sh

I'm making a script to synchronize directories with rsync over ssh. I come into trouble when I want to define a custom port. Suppose a normal working script would have a syntax:

```
#! /bin/sh

rval=2222
port="ssh -p $rval"

rsync --progress -av -e "$port" sflash@192.168.10.107:/home/sflash/Documents/tmp/tcopy/ /home/sflash/Documents/tmp/tcopy
```

the syntax when disclosing a custom port is `-e "ssh -p 2222"`. However, if I want to use a variable in this case like:

```
#! /bin/sh

rval=2222
port="-e \"ssh -p $rval\""

rsync --progress -av $port sflash@192.168.10.107:/home/sflash/Documents/tmp/tcopy/ /home/sflash/Documents/tmp/tcopy
```

This will not work likely due to some sort of interaction with IFS. I can completely avoid this scenario if I introduce an if statement to check if `port` is defined, but I am curious on the exact reason why this fails and if a solution exists to forcefully implement this method.

EDIT: sorry I am restricted to just posix shell

Comment: Why don't you use `"$port"` here as well?

Comment: because it doesn't work. I tried

Comment: `echo "$port"` expands to `-e "ssh -p 2222"` - isn't that what you want?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk could you give me an example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually provided enough detail to be certain, but I suspect you are hitting a common misconception.

When you do:

```
rval=2222
rsync --progress -av -e "ssh -p $rval" src dst
```

`rsync` is invoked with 6 arguments: `--progress`, `-av`, `-e`, `ssh -p 2222`, `src`, and `dst`.

On the other hand, when you do:

```
port="-e \"ssh -p $rval\""
rsync --progress -av $port src dst
```

`rsync` is invoked with 8 arguments: `--progress`, `-av`, `-e`, `"ssh`, `-p`, `2222"`, `src`, and `dst`.

You do not want the double quotes to be passed to `rsync`, and you do not want the `ssh -p 2222` to be split up into 3 arguments.  One (terrible) way to do what you want is to use `eval`.  But it seems what you really want is:

```
rval=2222
port="ssh -p $rval"
rsync --progress -av ${port:+-e "$port"} src dst
```

Now, if port is defined and not the empty string, `rsync` will be invoked with the additional arguments `-e` and `ssh -p 2222` (as desired), and if port is undefined or empty, neither the `-e` nor the `$port` argument will be used.

Note that this is a case where you must not use double quotes around `${port:+-e "$port"}`.  If you do so, then an empty string would be passed as an argument when `$port` is the empty string.  When `$port` is not the empty string, it would pass a single argument `-e ssh -p 2222` rather than splitting into 2 arguments `-e` and `ssh -p 2222`.

Comment: It works, thank you. I'm keeping on using parameter expansion way just so that I won't forget how shell expands my arguments